# 1781 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 after adding pods

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app that works fine and all but I am attempting to add CocoaPods for various reasons. However, upon adding CocoaPods I have been getting this `1781 duplicate symbols for architecture i386` error and I can't seem to find what framework is being duplicated. I have included screenshots of what was being imported by my program and by pods.
(BTW the 3 duplicate framework under pods were deleted but I still kept getting a duplicate error.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at these questions

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279622/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386-clang
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746699/duplicate-symbol-error-for-architecture-i386
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692385/error-running-simulator-duplicate-symbol-for-architecture-i386

Comment: I have read that, i was saying I cant locate or see a duplicate framework. Or is pods writing into my files somewhere so i can see if it is adding .h files i already have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through my project and kept deleting  framework and linker files. Deleting -Objc worked for me, not sure why since it wasnt in any of the pods project (not complaining either).